# How can I extract Objects from an array?

Tags: javascript, object

I have an array like

```
    var jsObjects = [
    {a: 1, b: 2}, 
    {a: 3, b: 4}, 
    {a: 5, b: 6}, 
    {a: 7, b: 8}
];
```

I want to extract objects from it. Or is there any way to convert this array into Object?

Comment: You want to do *what exactly* with those objects...?! What does "extract" mean exactly here?

Comment: I will get list of arrays(with objects in it) on click of a button. I want to use these objects in ng-repeat. If they are in arrays, It is difficult to use them in ng-repeat.

Comment: @Maverick are you using angularjs ?

Comment: Err... `ng-repeat` specifically **loops over arrays**. You're *supposed* to use `ng-repeat` with an array.

Comment: @Anil Islam Abhi, Yes I am using angularJS

Comment: *"is there any way to convert this array into Object"* - An object with *what* structure? Don't make us guess, [edit] the question to show the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create array with nested loop over object in controller. similar to this.

```
  var myArray = [];
  angular.forEach(jsObjects,function(value,key){
     angular.forEach(value,function(v,k){
        myArray.push(v);
     })
   })
  return myArray;
```

or use nested ng-repeat in view

```
<div ng-repeat="(key,value) in jsObject">
    <div ng-repeat="(k,v) in value">
      <span> {{v}} </span> 
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

So essentially what you have here is an array of objects. So at first you just treat the objects like any other items in an array, access them like so

```
var object = console.log(jsObjects[0]);
```

That allows you to extract the first object in the array. After that you would just treat it like any other object. So to get extract information from this object you would do like so

```
console.log(object["a"]);
```

or alternatively you could access it in just one line by doing like so

```
console.log(jsObjects[0]["a"]);
```

Answer (score 1):

To extract the objects you can access them like you would any element from an array.

For example, in a simple array like

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

you would access `3` with:

```
> arr[2]
< 3
```

In your array:

```
var jsObjects = [
  {a: 1, b: 2}, 
  {a: 3, b: 4}, 
  {a: 5, b: 6}, 
  {a: 7, b: 8}
];
```

you would access the 3rd object with:

```
> jsObjects[2]
< {a: 5, b: 6}
```

and you could access individual key/value pairs with:

```
> jsObjects[2].a
< 5
```